# how to create excel charts having strings in both x and y axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

I have a student data with Student Name and their grade (A/B/C/D/E.). Now I want to have a graph for this data.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  As it's written, your question is very vague and likely to be closed.  Please add some additional info about what you've tried and the specific problems you're having.

Comment: Hai, I was tried to plot a graph having two fields (NAME and Gradde like A,B,C..) but when I tried to select a chart it was showing only for a single student. And when I tried to use pivot chart then Y axis was scaling in Numbers but my requirements is to scale according to grade. Please concern for any clear view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add details.

Answer (score 0):

Open Ms Excel, select the column student name and grade, go to insert option click on chart tab, under that you will find create chart option under that choose whatever template you want and do whatever editing you want to do...

If you want to assign grade(A/B/C/D), I don't think its possible...You can assign A as 1, B as 2 and so on...

Comment: Is it possible by giving A as 1 B as 2 and so on.. in VBA coding and showing the output as A. B.. in Y axis of a chart..

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea: first calculate numeric grades into a new column,
the formula in that column would be `=5-(CODE(C2)-CODE("A"))` ...

and then set a custom formatting on the axis, to `[=5]"A";[=4] "B";[=3]"C";[=2]"D";[=1]"E";"-"`
... but I cannot get this to work in LibreOffice,
it USES at most three "conditions", where the last doesn't seem to check the condition inside the brackets.
The help section on the web doesn't say that there is a limit.

Now it might be that Excel does this correctly.

Example data, and a right click on the char Y-axis showing the menu:
[image: Format axis menu]

And here is the format setting:
[image: Format axis-Format]